# CKEditor ignoring BASEPATH in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, ckeditor, ckfinder

Installed CKEditor and CKFinder in a Laravel project, both in the Public/js folder

In my main page, I load a site specific .js file which contains

```
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/js/ckeditor/';
```

Also tried:

```
var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'http://localhost:8888/js/ckeditor/';
```

Then I load my ckeditor.js file

From my /Resources/Views/admin/newpage.blade.php view, I load up a text box and call CKEditor.replace().  Does it perfectly. I can add a new page, even edit them.

Problem occurs when I try to use the Browse server buttons, it tries to load the plugin from /admin/ckeditor/plugins/...    instead of /js/ckeditor/plugins/...

I have a feeling its something simple I am missing, but just not sure what.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you set the `basePath` property of `CKEDITOR.plugins` manually? Or adding an external resource like `CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('someNameForThePlugin', CKEDITOR_BASEPATH + '/js/ckeditor/', 'scriptFile.js')` and then add it as a extra plugin in the editor configuration? Check this: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Tutorial-create-external-plugin-for-CKEDITOR

Answer (score 3):

you have to write full address to file file this

```
<script>
  window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'http://example.com/path/to/libs/ckeditor/';
</script>
```

Comment: try to point to directory with relative ../../public/js/plugins

Answer (score 1):

use Symfony-2
laravel5 composer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with laravel and CKEditior.

The difference is I was facing this in plugin folder to give the icon of my custom button

`icon: this.path + 'mypath'`

solved my issue.

So you may also have to append your path after `this.path`

Hope it will sove yours too.